# How to Queue Python script execution calls?

Tags: python, process, queue, file-locking

I have a script which work on the arguments with which it is called(a file path), ie reads the file and extract the IP address and write it to a new file. Script is called multiple times without any time gap between the calls. I am having doubts whether this will work if I write a straight forward script just doing it's task. Will each call waits until the last write operation is completed? or each execution calls create a new process instances and have a clash when trying to open the same output file for writing?

Script is yet to be written. In the mean time I thought of asking a question here. I would like to know how things work in this context and do I need to implement something special here.

Comment: If you need synchronization, either wait for the previous script to terminate, or lock any resources (like files) that you use. Or keep the script running infinitely and check for new files on its own (either every x minutes, or with something like a [file system watchdog](https://pypi.org/project/watchdog/).)